# OpenShift Site not loading after pushing

Tags: python, django, openshift

after going through the below instructions, I reload my page yet I'm still seeing the default page of Openshift instead of the page of my site.

Openshift instructions I followed

```
 git clone ssh://517f4cdc5973cae128000169@newlocarte-locdada.rhcloud.com/~/git/newlocarte.git/
 cd newlocarte/
```

This will create a folder with the source code of your application. After making a change, add, commit, and push your changes.

```
 git add .
 git commit -m 'My changes'
 git push
```

In my Git command:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 262 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: restart_on_add=false
remote: Done
remote: restart_on_add=false
remote: Running .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build
remote: New python executable in /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//py
thon-2.7/virtenv/bin/python
remote: Installing setuptools..................done.
remote: Installing pip...............done.
remote: Running virtualenv with interpreter /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae12
  8000169//python-2.7/opt/bin/python
remote:   - Created/Updated virtenv and activated it.
remote:  - Found setup.py. Processing it ...
remote: running develop
remote: running egg_info
remote: creating YourAppName.egg-info
remote: writing requirements to YourAppName.egg-info/requires.txt
remote: writing YourAppName.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote: writing top-level names to YourAppName.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote: writing dependency_links to YourAppName.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote: writing manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: reading manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: writing manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: running build_ext
remote: Creating /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169/python-2.7/virtenv/
 lib/python2.7/site-packages/YourAppName.egg-link (link to .)
remote: YourAppName 1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
 remote:
 remote: Installed /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169/app-root/runtime/r
   epo
 remote: Processing dependencies for YourAppName==1.0
 remote: Searching for gevent==0.13.8
 remote: Best match: gevent 0.13.8
 remote: Processing gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
 remote: gevent 0.13.8 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
 remote:
 remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169/python-2.7/virtenv/lib
   /python2.7/site-packages/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
 remote: Searching for greenlet==0.4.0
 remote: Best match: greenlet 0.4.0
 remote: Processing greenlet-0.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
 remote: greenlet 0.4.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
 remote:
 remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169/python-2.7/virtenv/lib
   /python2.7/site-packages/greenlet-0.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
 remote: Finished processing dependencies for YourAppName==1.0
 remote:  - Done processing setup.py
 remote: Making script /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//python-2.7/vi
 rtenv/bin/pip relative
 remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//python-2.7/virtenv/b
   in/activate.csh cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts wi
  th #!/var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169/python-2.7/virtenv/bin/python)
  remote: Making script /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//python-2.7/vi
    rtenv/bin/pip-2.7 relative
 remote: Making script /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//python-2.7/vi
    rtenv/bin/easy_install relative
 remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//python-2.7/virtenv/b
     in/activate.fish cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts w
     ith #!/var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169/python-2.7/virtenv/bin/python)

 remote: Making script /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//python-2.7/vi
      rtenv/bin/easy_install-2.7 relative
 remote: Running .openshift/action_hooks/build
 remote: New python executable in /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae128000169//py
         thon-2.7/virtenv/bin/python
 remote: Installing setuptools..................done.
 remote: Installing pip...............done.
 remote: Running virtualenv with interpreter /var/lib/openshift/517f4cdc5973cae12
        8000169//python-2.7/opt/bin/python
 remote: Running .openshift/action_hooks/deploy
 remote: hot_deploy_added=false
 remote: MySQL already running
 remote: Done
 remote: Running .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy
  To ssh://517f4cdc5973cae128000169@newlocarte-locdada.rhcloud.com/~/git/  newlocarte.git/
   cd033bf..95121b4  master -> master
    Skizzy@H43K /c/Python27/Scripts/env/Scripts/art/newlocarte (master)
```

How can I make it load?

Comment: Could it be a caching problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ssh into the app gear and make sure your code got pushed onto the gear. To ssh into the gear, run the command "rhc ssh -a {appName}". Also make sure your application related files are under wsgi directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rhc app-restart <app> [--namespace NAME] [--app NAME]
```